# JQuery UI Sortable horizontal expandable container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm attempting to make a pair of JQuery UI sortable divs where you move items from one vertically expanding div to another horizontally expanding div (think something like a timeline). The idea is that you can drag an item up from the holder div onto the timeline div, and as you add items the div will expand to hold them all.

I've tried a few different CSS things, ranging from using floats and inline-blocks to making the container extremely wide by default (sort of worked, but I'd rathe not have all the extra space there by default, and it's still possible to run out of space), but I can't seem to make it expand horizontally, only vertically. Here's my current code:

JS:

```
jQuery( ".dragto ul.connect-sortable, .dragfrom ul.connect-sortable" ).sortable({
    items: "li:not(.empty)",
    connectWith: ".connect-sortable",
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",

    start: function(event, ui) { ui.placeholder.html('&nbsp;') },

    receive : function(event, ui ){

    },

    update : function(event, ui ){

    }
  }).disableSelection();
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="dragto">
    <ul class="connect-sortable">
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="dragfrom">
    <ul class="connect-sortable">
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul.connect-sortable {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: inline;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #bfb9b3;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.dragto {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.dragto ul.connect-sortable {
  height: 230px;
  /* width: 10000px; */
}


ul.connect-sortable li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FEFEFE;
  border: 2px solid #bfb9b3;
  float: left;
}

ul.connect-sortable li:hover {
  border: 2px solid #5cc7ee;
  background: #e5f6fb;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.ui-state-highlight {
  border: 2px dashed #D8D8D8 !important;
  background: #F0F0F0 !important;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.ui-sortable-helper {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #888888;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #888888;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #888888;
}
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1px;
}
```

Any ideas?

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GgqD7/1/)</kbd>